# International internal sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following simple VBA code using a German Excel version:

```
Sub German()
Tabelle1.Range("A1").Value = 1
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of Excel showing Tabelle1, Tabelle2, and Tabelle3]

In this VBA code I am referring to the internal sheet name "Tabelle1" which you can also see in the red circle on the attached image.

Now I want to internationalize my code so it can be used in every language.
How do I have to change my code to make the internal sheet name international?

Comment: You mean, you want to refer to the sheet? What about `Dim wsh As Worksheet: Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` or `Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")`?

Comment: I'd suggest to read [this article](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm).

Comment: As much as I believe in [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) I perfectly understand that this is a situation when a visual representation is more informative than a narrative (e.g. *typed*) one. Plus one.

Comment: @Maciej Los: The article is interesting but the issue is that once I change the german phrase "Tabelle1" to "Sheet1" as suggested in the article I get the runtime error 424.

Answer (score 2):

You can change both the name displayed in Excel and the name used as code name in the property window ("Eigenschaftenfenster" in German).

You can open this window via the View menu or (probably) pressing F4.

There you can inspect and change the properties of the worksheet.

Comment: Good catch. Renaming to a non-standard should be more than sufficient. Not having a DE-DE version at my disposal, I still expect you are correct.

Comment: Hi Fratyx, thanks for your answer. I have found the property window but I could not find which property I have to change to solve my issue. Where can I rename it to a non-standard as jeeped suggested?

Comment: There is a `(Name)` property (with brackets) on the top of the list which represents the code name of the worksheet. The `Name` property without brackets is the user visible name.

Comment: Now I understand your solution. It is a nice idea. The only issue I can see is that if I have many end-users from different countries it might be difficult since I would have to change the property in every different language. Except Excel knows how to convert it in another language. I will have to test it.